# How to increase size of a button on hover without pushing other Flex items to the side

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox, hover

I have a flexbox with 2 buttons as seen in the images below. I made it so that when I hover over one the button size increases. But the problem I have is that when I hover over one it pushes the other button to the side. How can I make it so that doesnt happen?

[image: Before hovering]

[image: After hovering on "Learn more" button]

Sorry if its not clear its a subtle change.

Here is my code:

```css
:root{
    --Primary: #1c1c1e;
    --Secondary: #2c2c2e;
    --Text: #fff;
    --TextGradient: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #e36577, #f6edb2);
    --Gradient: linear-gradient(45deg, #e36577, #f6edb2)
}
body{
    background-color: var(--Secondary);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
*{
    font-family: 'system-ui', sans-serif;
    color: var(--Text);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
button{
    --border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: var(--Primary);
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
    
}

button:hover{
    font-size: 17px;
}

.about-btns{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 30px;
}


.highlight-btn{
    --border-width: 5px;
    background: var(--Gradient);
    z-index: 1;
}
.highlight-btn::before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: calc(100% - calc(var(--border-width) * 2));
    width: calc(100% - calc(var(--border-width) * 2));
    background: var(--Primary);

    position: absolute;
    top: var(--border-width);
    left: var(--border-width);

    border-radius: calc(var(--border-radius) - var(--border-width));
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-btns">
  <button class="highlight-btn">See my work</button>
  <button>Learn more</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Rather than using font-size to increase the size of the button use transform: scale property like this:

```
.about-btns > button:hover{
    transform: scale(1.04);
}
```